# Formation of words having length 5 by using 2 letters

Tags: permutations

In how many ways can 5 letter words be formed with 2 letters - Y and N.
Ex - YYYNN, NNNYY etc.

Comment: did my answer not help you

Comment: If not feel free to point out any errors

Answer (score -1):

For each position, you can either have a Y or an N. so for the first letter, there are 2 possibilities, the second letter also has 2  possibilities and so on. So you answer will be 2*2*2*2*2=$2^5=32$. Generalising it, for an m letter word with n letter possibilities and repitition will have a total of $n^m$ word possibilities